# Upgraded to Xcode 5 and now receiving lots of "Issue" messages

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5

I recently upgraded to Xcode 5 from 4.6 and I usually use phonegap 2.9 to build my apps, I've noticed that when I clean or archive an app I get a lot of alerts, my apps still archives correctly but my question is should I be worried that something will eventually break? Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample 1]

[image: sample 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, everything will work just as before upgrading to XCode 5. 
However, Apple put these compile-time checks there intentionally! My policy is to treat compiler warnings as errors, and investigate each of them. I've found that XCode 5 has improved substantially in this field, for example it now generates a compile error on control reaching end of non-void functions - XCode 4.6 emitted simply a warning.

Comment: That is a good approach to use, I'll look into these warnings. I just wanted a little piece and mind. :) Thanks.